# Namespace is not visible in class file

Tags: asp.net

I am creating web application using vs 2008.I want to create sql_Helper class.I know web application does not contain App_Code folder.I manually created folder app_code in my web application and put class into it.But namespace system.Data.sqlClient and System.Web.Configuration is not visible,but that visible other web pages which are not in app_code

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are referencing these dlls.

Answer (score 0):

The App_Code folder doesn't work with web applications.

App_Code folder is a special ASP.NET **RUNTIME** folder…  Any files in this folder are compiled by ASP.NET when your site is actually running on the server...  This essentially allows you to drop random class/code files in this folder to be compiled on the server side.

In your web application that you compile into a dll at compile time, this will be a problem.

App_Code folders are meant for web site projects and not for web application projects.

If you do want to call your folder App_Code, mark the classes inside to have a build action as compile.

Comment: What shall I do now?Where I place my class file which contain connection code?

Comment: You could rename the folder to something else.

Comment: I solved my problem by doing build action from content to compile.

Comment: Ok, but you will have to do that for any file that you add to that folder. Every once in a while someone forgets that and it wastes time.